# Удаление во фрагменте с помощью gridview.viewholder'a

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, gridview

У меня есть следующий xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_upload"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/disable_info" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_close_btn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/close_btn" />

<md.simpals.md999.views.ProgressWheel
    android:id="@+id/loader_photo"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_progress_small"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_progress_small"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    custom:matProg_barColor="@color/progress_bar"
    custom:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />
```

Мне в коде фрагмента нужно обработать нажатие на photo_close_btn(по типу как написал ниже Sergey Gornostaev):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Реакция на клик
    }
});
}
```

Единственное что мне нужно передать эту //Реакцию на клик в Gridview .Holder, пробовал писать нечто похожее(должна при клике на photo_close_btn удалять элемент):

```
    class UploadHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.photo_close_btn)      
        ImageView photoClose;

        public UploadHolder(View view) {     
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
                 }

        @OnClick(R.id.iv_upload)      
        void clickImage() {          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

А в чём проблема? В `onCreateView` фрагмента назначайте обработчик для `photo_close_btn`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Реакция на клик
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: супер
а в //Реакция на клик - такое подойдёт?
 controls.remove(getAdapterPosition()).getImageUploads().get(position);
так как удалять по нажатию на клик, он должен удалять.

Comment: Судя по методу `getAdapterPosition()` класса `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, приведённый в вопросе макет - это макет элемента `RecyclerView`. Так?

Comment: да, всё правильно.

Comment: Тогда установку обработчика лучше перенести в конструктор ViewHolder'а.

Comment: примерно следующее?
class Buttons extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.photo_close_btn)
        LinearLayout mCloseButton;

@OnClick(R.id.photo_close_btn)
        public void clickCancel(View view) {
            if (itemClick != null)
                itemClick.clickCancel(getAdapterPosition()).getImageUploads().get(‌​position));
        }

что то намудрил...) ну направление верное?)